# Issue with socket.io updating component to show new message in chatroom

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, reactjs, socket.io

I am building a chat app with React, Node/Express and socket.io. I have my sockets successfully set to my express server via http.createServer. I have a listener on client and server listening for new messages coming into the chat room. Ideally, I want each instance of the chat to be updated when there is an additional message, like any chat room that ever existed :)

Now I have a successful listen between client and server. I know because of a console.log server-side. However, I am not re-rendering the chat component when I submit a new message from a different instance.

So my code in my client-side (again React) component is as follows and I am using the socket CDN with script tags in my index.html (script tags not shown):

Socket CDN here

var socket = io('')

So that is the socket you see client side :

```
componentDidMount() {
  return axios.get(`api/messages`)
    .then((result) => {
      if (result.data.length) {
        this.setState({ 
          messages: [ ...this.state.messages, ...result.data] 
        } , () => { 
          console.log("The state after messages are mounted : ", this.state) 
        })
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => { throw err})
      socket.on('new message', msg => {
      this.newMessage(msg);
    })
};

newMessage(msg) {
  this.setState({
    messages: [...this.state.messages, msg]
  }, () => {
    this.setState({ message: '' })
    return this.scrollToBottom()
  });
};


onSubmitMessage(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const content = this.state.message;

  const msg = {
    content,
    createdAt : new Date(),
    userId : "one",
    chatRoomId : "two"
  }
  axios.post(`api/messages/`, msg)
  .then(() => {
    this.newMessage(msg);
    socket.emit('new message', msg); //HERE'S THE SOCKETS IN ACTION
  })
};
```

Here is the server-side code Node/Express:

```
//in server.js
const io = new socketIo(server)
require('./socketEvents')(io);
const connections = [];
```

Then a separate file for my socket events
    //in socketEvents.js

```
module.exports = (io) => {

  io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log("Beautiful sockets are connected")

    socket.once('disconnect', () => {
      console.log("socket is disconnected");
    });

    //DOESN'T DO ANYTHING YET 
    socket.on('join global', (username) => {
      socket.join(username);
      console.log("New user in the global chat : ", username)
    });

    socket.on('new message', (msg) => {
      console.log("The new message from sockets : ", msg);
      socket.emit('new message', msg.content);
    });

  });
}
```

My sockets server side are linked up with the client. I'm just not seeing new messages in different instances. Is it because I'm not re-rendering after the server receives the message?

Thanks in advance, please let me know if you need me to clarify anything.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out... I'm going to leave this post up with a walkthrough in an attempt to help others who are having trouble with sockets. I may post a blog about it. Will update if I do.

So the code listens on the client side for a message to be sent inside of my onSubmitMessage function.

```
onSubmitMessage(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); //prevents HTML <form> from going on its own post
  const content = this.state.message;

  //Create message object
  const msg = {
    content,
    createdAt : new Date(),
    userId : "one",
    chatRoomId : "two"
  }

  //HERE'S THE IMPORTANT PART!!!
  axios.post(`api/messages/`, msg)
  .then(() => {

    // wrapped in a promise, send a handler to server called 
    // ('new message') with the message object
    this.newMessage(msg);
    socket.emit('new message', msg);
  })
  .then(() => {
    //Another promise then waits for the handler to come back from server 

    //*****IMPORTANT*************
    //Then invoke newMessage function to get the post on all sockets
    socket.on('message', (msg) => {
      this.newMessage(msg);
    })
  })
```

};

Now on the server side this is what's happening:

```
// This is where the listener is for the client side handle
socket.on('new message', (msg) => {
  // broadcast.emit will send the msg object back to client side and
  // post to every instance expcept for the creator of the message
  socket.broadcast.emit('message', msg);
});
```

SO the data path is (C) for client, (S) for server:

receive message object from user and -------->

(C)socket.emit('new message') -----> (S) socket.on('new message') -------> (S) socket.broadcast.emit('message') --------> (C)socket.on('message')

Back in the client side, I can invoke my newMessage function, which will set the message to state so I can display it.

I hope someone finds this useful! Surprisingly, this seems to go relatively unanswered on Stack. If anyone has any questions feel free to ask!